Getting error to obtain FUTURE OPTION option chain from Interactive Brokers through R Ibrokers library
I am trying to get ES Future Option's option-chain data from InteractiveBrokers through R Ibrokers library as below:

tws <- twsConnect(port = 7497)
# Check if connection is successful
isConnected(tws)
[1] TRUE

es_option_template <- twsOPT(symbol = "ES", right = "P", exch = "CME", strike = 5790, local = "EWU4 P5790")
es_contract_details <- reqContractDetails(conn = tws, Contract = es_option_template)
Error in if (curMsg != .twsIncomingMSG$CONTRACT_DATA) { : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In writeBin(as.character(request), con) : problem writing to connection

What could I be doing wrong here?

Try specifying i) local symbol Symbol (EWU4 P5790), ii) security type (FOP), iii) currency (USD) and iv) exchange (CME) (as per
https://github.com/enricoschumann/IButils#finding-the-contract-specification)
